# My VS can't stop at the crash location while debugging

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am using VS 2010. While debuging my C# website, if there is any run time error, my debug internet browser will crash and only the triangle on the left-bottom roughly shows the error info. Previously in the normal situation, my VS could stop at the code where this crash happens in case of run time error occurs.

Is there any setting in VS that I can restore this feature? BTW, I installed Just-Code but disabled its add-in in VS, don't know if this software caused this problem.

Thanks,

Wei

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VS, in the toolbar click on the Debug -> Exceptions.

Then check the Throw checkbox for the Exceptions you are interested in.

Comment: +1 for telepathic skills :) I could not sense that lwconquer was debugging Silverlight based on the question.

Comment: My mistake, Alexei. I should mention that in my original post. Thanks for your help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Check out is Silverlight debugging is turned on for the project by mistake. You can debug either JavaScript OR Silverlight.

Comment: Thanks, Alexei. But I am working on Silverlight and can't turn off silverlight debug.